# position of const in declarations matters

Tags: pointers, constants, cython

I was experimenting with writing a python wrapper for the C `libsox` library where the developers seem to use the convention of placing the `const` keyword *after* the c type e.g.,

```
sox_bool
LSX_API
sox_is_playlist(
LSX_PARAM_IN_Z char const * filename 
);
```

However, Cython raised a syntax error when trying to compile this. Switching the order of `char` and `const` in the above example lets Cython compile successfully.

As far as I know, the order of `char` and `const` is interchangeable in C. So is this a Cython bug? Or is this mentioned somewhere in the Cython documentation as known limitation? Because I couldn't find any mention of it.

EDIT:
I've opened a github issue for cython [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1475)

Comment: Seems weird to me that const ordering can be interchangeable. If the pointer itself was const (instead of a regular pointer to const char) , could you put the const before OR after the *? If that's the case, how would the compiler know which you wanted to be const... The pointer or the characters? Deep thoughts...

Comment: @c.fogelklou `const` can come before and/or after the *, but the ordering of the typename and the first const (before the *) shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug we had to work around in our code base too. I don't know if it is mentioned anywhere.